# Why does the dipolar Hamiltonian factorize after applying the rotating wave approximation?

Tags: quantum-spin, representation-theory, dipole

The Hamiltonian for two dipole-interacting spins is

$$H = \frac{-J_0}{r^3}\left[3(\vec{S}_1\cdot\hat{r})(\vec{S}_2\cdot \hat{r}) - \vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2\right]$$

here $\hat{r}$ is the unit vector pointing from spin 1 to spin 2, $r$ is the distance between them, and $\vec{S}=(S^x,S^y,S^z)$ is the vector of spin matrices. When you write this out as a matrix, the various coefficients of that matrix have different dependence on $\hat{r}$, so this angular dependence doesn't factor out. However if you put the spins in a strong magnetic field (which we'll point along the Z axis for convenience) and use the rotating wave approximation (RWA), the resulting Hamiltonian factorizes into a scalar angular dependence $1-3\cos^2\theta$ and a separate term with all the operators, where $\theta$ is the angle that $\hat{r}$ makes to the Z axis

$$H_{\text{RWA}} = \frac{-J_0}{r^3}(1-3\cos^2\theta)[S^+_1S^-_2+S^-_1S^+_2-S^z_1S^z_2]$$

where $S^\pm_i$ are the raising and lowering operators $S^\pm_i\equiv (S^x_i \pm i S^y_i)/2$. It's easy to derive this result (see below) but it's never been clear to me why it had to come out so simple. In fact, this factorization crucially relies on the factor of 3 in the original dipole-dipole Hamiltonian, so an answer has to explain why this 3 couldn't have been something else. Furthermore, for particles with spin greater than 1/2, this factorization does not occur if we do something more complicated, such as applying an additional quadrapole field like $\Delta(S^x)^2$ to both spins.

So the question; why does this factorization occur, and what guarantees mathematically that will it happen?

### Refresher: the standard derivation

I figure it doesn't hurt to recap the standard derivation here, which is pretty simple. To go from $H$ to $H_{\text{RWA}}$, we can first set $\hat{r}=[\sin\theta,0,\cos\theta]$ without loss of generality. When we expand out $H$, we get

$$H = \frac{-J_0}{r^3}\left[3(S^x_1 S^x_2 \sin^2\theta + S^z_1S^z_2 \cos^2\theta + \cos\theta\sin\theta(S^x_1S^z_2+S^z_1 S^x_2)) - \vec{S}_1\cdot \vec{S}_2\right]$$

Now the RWA simplifies things: $S^x_1S^x_2 = (S^+_1+S^-_1)(S^-_2+S^+_2) \rightarrow S^+_1S^-_2 + S^-_1 S^+_2$ and likewise for $S^y_1 S^y_2$. Also the cross-terms vanish $S^x_1S^z_2,~S^z_1 S^x_2 \rightarrow 0$ because these operators flip one spin without changing the other, and this is a large change in energy when the external field is large. A few lines of algebra gives $H_{\text{RWA}}$. If you replace the 3 above with $\alpha$, then you'll find that $H_\text{RWA}$ only factorizes for $\alpha=3$.  This 3 ultimately comes from the spherical harmonics and the Legendre polynomial $P_2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)$, so perhaps there is a nice simple representation-theory argument for its role here.